# Break word with CSS?

Tags: css, text, cpu-word, break

I work with a web site and i have many long word in my menu. I would like to display them in two line but not one. I used word-wrap proprety in CSS.

```
{word-wrap: break-word}
```

But this property breaks the word.

For example I have : `Solution for enterprise`

When I use  the word-wrap property I get this :

```
Solution for enter
prise
```

Whereas I would like to have:

```
Solution
for enterprise
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your menu code please? :)

Comment: `word-wrap` won't break words for you in the way you want, you need to use `<br>` there

Comment: @putvande I've rolled back your edit, as the meaning of the question was lost...

Comment: That happens automatically in a div [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/rzq5e/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Various options, some mentioned in the comments:

- set a width on the link wrapper (`li` or whatever) so that the words naturally wrap;
- add a `<br>` element where you want the words to wrap;
- wrap a `span` around the word(s) to wrap and set the span to `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

Use white-space attribute of css instead.